# Weird width of UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, width

I do not know why i get this problem. I have a custom cell emmbeded in a small UIView , both have size 280 x 50 . I'm using `colorWithPatternImage` to set background color for cell. My image (for background ) has also 280 x 50. But anyway drawing cell background gets wrong.
You can look at screenshots below

[image]

Why I get this ? And how to avoid it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you define your cell's layout in IB, try making it 320 points wide there (with approprite autoresize masks).
My guess is that the cell (but not its subviews) is created 320 pt wide anyway and then resized to tableview's width (280 pt) with the autoresize masks.
Another option is to disable autoresizing for the cell.

Comment: i did how you said but anyway still same issue.